# FastAPI authorization via decorator

Tags: python, fastapi

The following FastAPI app can be executed, returns a valid JWT for the POST request to the endpoint `http://localhost:8000/login` with `{"username": "admin", "password": "password"}` as the body. Then this JWT can be sent in the header of a GET request to the endpoint `http://localhost:8000/items` and decoded again. The GET request as shown below in `test.py` works if the decorator `@authorize(["admin"])` is removed in the `item_routes.py` file. Without the decorator it returns the following:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "item A"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when the decorator stays in the code, the FastAPI app logs `422 Unprocessable Entity` and returns:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "query",
        "kwargs"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

What needs to be changed in the code to have `@authorize(["admin"])` work when running `test.py`?

```
# test.py
import requests


base_url = "http://localhost:8000"

login_url = base_url + "/login"
login_data = {"username": "admin", "password": "password"}
response = requests.post(login_url, json=login_data)
token = response.json()["token"]
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
print(headers)  # {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJh... and so on'}

items_url = base_url + "/items"
response = requests.get(items_url, headers=headers)
print(response.json()) # {'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'kwargs'], 
                       # 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}

item_id = 1
item_url = f"{base_url}/items/{item_id}"
response = requests.get(item_url, headers=headers)
print(response.json()) # {'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'kwargs'], 
                       # 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

```
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from item_routes import router as item_router
from login import router as login_router
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(item_router)
app.include_router(login_router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

```
# login.py
router = APIRouter()


class Login(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str


@router.post("/login")
async def login(login: Login):
    if login.username == "admin" and login.password == "password":
        role = "admin"
        token = create_jwt(login.username, role)
        return {"token": token}
    raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
```

```
# jwt.py
from jose import jwt


SECRET_KEY = "secret-key"


def create_jwt(username, role):
    payload = {"sub": username, "role": role}
    token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
    return token
```

```
# item_routes.py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from authorization import authorize

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/items")
@authorize(["admin"])
async def get_items():
    return {"items": [{"id": 1, "name": "item A"}]}


@router.get("/items/{item_id}")
@authorize(["admin"])
async def get_item(item_id):
    return {"item": item_id}
```

```
# authorization.py
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer
from jose import jwt, JWTError
from jwt import SECRET_KEY


ROLES = {"admin": []}


async def get_current_user(token=Depends(HTTPBearer())):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token.credentials, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
        username = payload.get("sub")
        role = payload.get("role")
        if role not in ROLES:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid role")
        print({"username": username, "role": role})
        return {"username": username, "role": role}
    except JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token")


def authorize(roles):
    def decorator(func):
        async def wrapper(current_user=Depends(get_current_user), **kwargs):
            if current_user["role"] not in roles:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Unauthorized")
            return await func(**kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, I do not see any `**kwargs` that you are providing for the `wrapper`function from request URL. If so, can you remove the extra parameter and execute the `test.py`

```
def authorize(roles):
    
    def decorator(func):
        async def wrapper(current_user=Depends(get_current_user)):
            if current_user["role"] not in roles:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Unauthorized")
            return await func()

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

[image: Output screenshot with items returned]

Comment: Thanks Prudhviraj, you are right, `**kwargs` was not used in the above example for endpoint `http://localhost:8000/items`. However, if more endpoints are added, such as a `http://localhost:8000/items/{item_id}` endpoint, then the `authorize` function needs the `**kwargs`. I added the `http://localhost:8000/items/{item_id}` endpoint above to make it clear why `**kwargs` is used in the `authorize` function.

Answer (score 1):

[example from docs][1], with my realization (actual on 2023):

```
async def verify_token(gp_id: str, access_token: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    db_user = db.query(YalynkaUser).join(AuthHash).filter(AuthHash.hash == access_token).first()
    if db_user is None or db_user.gp_id != gp_id:
        raise credentials_exception


@app.get('/users/{gp_id}', tags=['User'], response_model=schemas.YalynkaUser, dependencies=[Depends(verify_token)])
async def get_user(gp_id: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)): інший gp_id
    db_user = db.query(YalynkaUser).filter(YalynkaUser.gp_id == gp_id).first()
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='User not found with the given ID')
    return db_user
```